# Cannot find module 'true-case-path'

Tags: angularjs, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I am not able to run npm start am getting the below error

```
  E:\angular2\projects2018\angularFlex>npm install

> node-sass@4.7.2 install E:\angular2\projects2018\angularFlex\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'true-case-path'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\angular2\projects2018\angularFlex\node_modules\node-sass\lib\extensions.js:11:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: are you using NVM for Windows to install Node?

Comment: Windows  only   used

Comment: also have it on ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and Fedora 27

Answer (score 2):

You might want to update your nodejs & npm, i just installed 9.4.0 (npm 5.4.2) and its fixed!

Comment: After update, I removed package-lock.json and node_modules and it worked!